# Rearranging Pokemon Experience Formula to make Level the Subject

Tags: calculus

As the title suggests, I am trying to rearrange some of the formulas for calculating experience based on level to be the other way around (calculating level based on experience).

I am having trouble with rearranging this formula for **n** (n being level):

$$EXP = \frac{n^3(100-n)}{50} $$

What I have done so far is:

1. **multiplied** the 50 out

$${EXP}\times{50} = {n^3(100-n)} $$

2. **expanded** the brackets
   $${EXP} \times {50} = 100n^3 - n^4 $$

But I don't know how to continue from here to make **n** the subject so that I can calculate the **Level** based on **Experience**. Do I **divide** the 100 out, if so, would that affect $n^4$?

**Note:** The links to the original formulas can be [found here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Experience#Relation_to_level).

Comment: You made one error: you needed to multiply by 50, not divide. Anyway, the equation can only technically be solved analytically, using the cumbersome quartic formula. In practice you would use a numerical solution.

Comment: @Ian I realised my error and quickly edited my question. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I plugged it into Maple even and it refuses to give a closed form solution, even though it's definitely possible. Just not easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As 6005 answered, you try to find $n$ such that the equation $$f(n)=n^4-100 n^3 +50 a=0$$ and, according to the link, this formula applies for $0\leq n \leq 50$ (and $a<125000$). As said, analytical solutions of quartic polynomials are not so funny and it could be easier to use a numerical method such as Newton. Starting from a guess $n_0$, the method will update it according to $$n_{k+1}=n_k-\frac{f(n_k)}{f'(n_k)}$$ that is to say $$n_{k+1}=\frac{n_k^3 (3 n_k-200)-50 a}{4 (n_k-75) n_k^2}$$ So, start at, say $n_0=25$ and iterate.

For illustration purposes, let us take $a=56789$; the iterates will then be $$n_1=38.3406$$ $$n_2=35.3914$$ $$n_3=35.2673$$ $$n_4=35.2671$$ which is the solution for six significant figures. All of that can easily be done using Excel.

You can improve the starting point using $n_0=a^{1/3}$ (this will be clear if you make a log-log plot of $n^4-100n^3$) and the first iterate of Newton method will be $$n_1=\frac{\left(3 \sqrt[3]{a}-250\right) \sqrt[3]{a}}{4 \left(\sqrt[3]{a}-75\right)}$$ which seems to be very good. For the illustrating case, this will give $n_1=35.3986$.

A still better approximation could be obtained using the simplest Pade approximant (do not worry : you will learn about them !). It will give $$n\approx \frac{650 a^{2/3}-3 a-30000 \sqrt[3]{a}}{-5 a^{2/3}+900 \sqrt[3]{a}-37500}$$ which, for the test case, will give $n\approx 35.2802$.

More accurate formulae could be made. Just post if you want better approximations.

**Edit**

Taking into account your last comments, for an exact solution use Newton
$$n_{k+1}=\frac{n_k^3 (3 n_k-200)-50 a}{4 (n_k-75) n_k^2}$$ and choose $$n_0=50\, \big(\frac a {125000}\big)^{0.4306}$$ obtained minimizing $$\Phi(\alpha)=\int_0^{50}\Big(\frac{n^3(100-n) }{50}-125000 \big(\frac n {50}\big)^\alpha  \Big)^2 \,dn$$ This exactly matches both end points and leads to an error of less than one unit over the whole range. Applied to $a=56789$, this gives $n_0=35.5985$ and the iterative process converges to the exact solution in a couple of iterations.

A more empirical (but much better) model could be $$n \approx 43.2633 \,x^{0.345438}+6.63856\, x^{1.33377}$$ where $x=\frac a {125000}$ (notice that the exponents are almost $\frac 13$ and $\frac 43$). The maximum error is smaller than $0.1$ over the whole range. For the test value, the result would be $35.2603$.

**Edit**

We can get the **exact** solution to the problem. Let us define $N=\frac n {50}$ and $A=\frac a {125000}$. This makes the equation to solve $N^3(N-2)+A=0$ which is a "quite simple" quartic. Now, let us define $$Z=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 A^2-16 A^3}+9 A}$$ $$T=\sqrt{\frac{2\ 2^{2/3} A}{\sqrt[3]{3} Z}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2} Z}{3^{2/3}}+1}$$ This leads to $$N=\frac{T+1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2}{T}-\frac{2\ 2^{2/3} Y}{\sqrt[3]{3} Z}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}
   Z}{3^{2/3}}+2}$$

Comment: I did a power law fit, by doing log-log least squares of $y=100x^3-x^4$ on $x=1,2,\dots,50$. I get $y=\exp(4.8797)x^{2.802}=131.6x^{2.802}$. That inverts to $x=0.1753y^{0.3569}$. Converting back to the old variables, this gives $n=0.7082a^{0.3569}$. This is a decent fit until around $n=40$. In particular, it gives the correct integer part of $n$ in your test case, which $a^{1/3}$ does not. (This is still a good answer, I'm just providing a small refinement.)

Comment: Note that the situation for rather large $n$ is pretty bad in both of our cases. For $a=4.5 \cdot 10^6$, the answer should be around $43$, but your guess is about $165$ while mine is about $168$.

Comment: @Ian. The formula is supposed fot $a \leq 1250000$

Comment: Oh. Then the $n$ range should only go up to $25$...

Comment: Thank you for the information. I do want to get the formula as accurate as possible, and since I will be programming the formula in, I don't think the Newton method would work well due to the derivative. Would RK4 be a viable method for approximating this (I don't have to check for the level often).

Also for the Pade approximant, I couldn't get it to work in the form you gave to me (I got a result over 300 million (could be arithmetic errors)), do I use it as is or in an ODE?

Comment: @Hayden. The exact solution is given by Newton method (I added the formula to my answer).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh okay, but the Newton method requires $f'(n_k)$, which I don't think is possible to do (or very difficult to achieve) in programming. An approximation of $f'(n_k)$ would mean less accuracy, which I ideally don't want as I want to try and make it as close to the real thing without resorting to Binary Searching an array. 

Are there alternatives?

Comment: Nevermind, my browser was screwing up and didn't see your new formula.

Comment: @Hayden. The equation is $f(n)=n^4-100 n^3 +50 a$; so $f'(n)=4n^3-300n^2$ and for the update I wrote it. It is very simple.

Comment: Thank you for your effort that you have put into finding various solutions to this problem. I am wondering on how you come to the conclusions on what values you used, in particular, the **quartic formula**, as I want to try and apply these types of formulas for the other experience formulas.

Comment: You are very welcome ! Be sure that I had a lot of fun and, for that, I thank you. The quartic has been the most difficult part (you noticed the complexity, I hope !). Look at Wikipedia for the solution of quartic polynomials. For the other formulae (the third is not the most pleasant), I think that we can develop nice approximations and polish the solution with Newton method. Let me know if you need help. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to solve
$$
n^4 - 100n^3 + 50 \text{EXP} = 0
$$
for $n$. Since the highest power of $n$ is $4$, this is known as a **quartic equation**. Fortunately, just as there is the *quadratic formula* for when the highest power is $2$, there is a *quartic formula* for when the highest power is $4$. (In fact, there *is* no formula to solve these things when the highest power is $5$ or more!)

Unfortunately, the quartic formula is EXTREMELY long, as you can see in [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Quartic_Formula.svg).
But it is simpler when some of the coefficients are zero, as in your case.
The instructions for solving the quartic can be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).
First you will need to compute $p$ and $q$, then $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_1$, then $S$ and $Q$, and finally you can plug them in to get the roots.

(If you're having trouble with it, let me know in a comment and I may be able to come back later to do the computation myself.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will let you know how it goes when I get home.